# Trying to turn some old ifelse code to case_when

Tags: r, tidyverse

So I have some old ifelse code (below) that I am trying to redo using case_when which I am failrly inexperienced with.

```
complete_data$type<-ifelse(grepl("Eneg",complete_data$Sample_code),"Negative",
                           ifelse(grepl("PCRneg",complete_data$Sample_code),"Negative",
                                  ifelse(grepl("DNApos",complete_data$Sample_code),"DNApositive",
                                         ifelse(grepl("PCRpos",complete_data$Sample_code),"PCRpositive",
                                         ifelse(grepl("Empty",complete_data$Sample_code),"Empty","Sample")))))
```

My initial attempt gets the first line working

```
complete_data$type <- case_when((grepl("Eneg", complete_data$Sample_code) ~ "Negative"))
```

But then my attempts to get the other ifelse statements in have all failed so far. Would anybody have any suggestions?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative without the additional `stringr` package would be:

```
libraries("tidyverse")
complete_data <- complete_data %>% mutate(type = case_when(
 grepl("Eneg", Sample_code) | grepl("PCRneg", Sample_code) ~ "Negative",
 grepl("DNApos", Sample_code) ~ "DNApositive"
 grepl("PCRpos", Sample_code) ~ "PCRpositive"
 grepl("Empty", Sample_code) ~ "Empty"
 TRUE ~ "Sample"
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_detect`/`grepl` for pattern matching and use `case_when` in the following way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

complete_data %>%
  mutate(type = case_when(str_detect(Sample_code, 'Eneg|PCRneg') ~ 'Negative', 
                          str_detect(Sample_code, 'DNApos') ~ 'DNApositive', 
                          str_detect(Sample_code, 'PCRpos') ~ 'PCRpositive',
                          str_detect(Sample_code, 'Empty') ~ 'Empty', 
                          TRUE ~ 'Sample')) -> complete_data
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!